# how do I manage multiple clicks in cardview with recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am using cardview with recyclerview in Android.

Inside one card View I am implementing multiple buttons....

So,
How can I implement different click events for each button

for example :
[image]

> I am not able to use Intent to call one more activity for different
>   click options
>
> If I click Image it have to goto one activity
>
> If I click description it have to goto another activity

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new CardAdapter();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
}
```

**CardAdapter**

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List<Items> mItems;

public CardAdapter() {
    super();
    mItems = new ArrayList<Items>();
    Items nature = new Items();
    nature.setName("The Great Barrier Reef");
    nature.setDes("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
    nature.setThumbnail(R.drawable.great_barrier_reef);
    mItems.add(nature);

    nature = new Items();
    nature.setName("Grand Canyon");
    nature.setDes("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
    nature.setThumbnail(R.drawable.grand_canyon);
    mItems.add(nature);

    nature = new Items();
    nature.setName("Baltoro Glacier");
    nature.setDes("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
    nature.setThumbnail(R.drawable.baltoro_glacier);
    mItems.add(nature);

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_card_item, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    Items nature = mItems.get(i);
    viewHolder.tvNature.setText(nature.getName());
    viewHolder.tvDesNature.setText(nature.getDes());
    viewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageResource(nature.getThumbnail());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public ImageView imgThumbnail;
    public TextView tvNature;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imgThumbnail = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
        tvNature = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nature);

    }
}
}
```

**Items**

```
public class Items {
private String mName;
private String mDes;
private int mThumbnail;

public String getName() {
    return mName;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.mName = name;
}

public String getDes() {
    return mDes;
}

public void setDes(String des) {
    this.mDes = des;
}

public int getThumbnail() {
    return mThumbnail;
}

public void setThumbnail(int thumbnail) {
    this.mThumbnail = thumbnail;
}

}
```

Comment: what is the issue that you met with when you tried to add click listener. or did you tried to add a click listener?

Comment: I am using like " public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> ". I am implementing onClickListener, But I am not able to use 'Intent' to call one more activity. Because I am already extends RecyclerView.Adapter so, I can't extends Activity class ....

Comment: you better post your code

Comment: I updated my code .... Please help me out ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass in a `Context` to the adapter class. then you can call `startActivity()` using that.

1.Change your `Adapter` constructor like this

```
private Context context
public CardAdapter(Context context) {
  this.context = context;
  ....//your remaining code
}
```

2.change your `onBindViewHolder` like this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    Items nature = mItems.get(i);
    viewHolder.tvNature.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,TargetActivity.class)
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);)
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    ...//remaining code
}
```

3.And now in `onCreate()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ....
    mAdapter = new CardAdapter(this); //change this line
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Comment: This has some drawbacks - for example starting activity requires additional flags as though it was run from new task.

Comment: @dominik4142 And what else would you suggest?

Comment: I would supply instance of custom listener interface (either in constructor or via set... method) that would be run when certain action has to be performed. That way fragment can forward its parent activity instance (beware leaks though) or open activities on its own.

Comment: @dominik4142 You mean an Interface??

Comment: You also don't need to pass Context via the constructor either. You can get it from the ViewHolder. viewHolder.itemView.getContext()

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your custom click listener that is able to determine which view was clicked (or a couple of different, each for different view), forward class implementing it to adapter (for example containing fragment/activity) and then in `onBindViewHolder` method set this reference as `onClickListener` on views that you need.

Comment: I am using like
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder>

If I am implementing onClickListener, I am not able to use 'Intent' to call one more activity.

Because I am already extends RecyclerView.Adapter